# validation in clone not working using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Working on validation in clone using jquery with my current code.

1. If the user click next button initially without filling any of the mandatory field it was showing the error message **You have missed 4 fields. Please fill before submitted.**
2. If the user click addmore button from the form if the user not filling any of the field it should alert message says success.
3. If the user fill any one of the field in the clone if click next button it should says total **You have missed 7 fields. Please fill before submitted.**.
4. If the user click remove button then if user click the next button it should say  **You have missed 4 fields. Please fill before submitted.**

With my current code i have achieved the first point but not 2,3,4 i am confused kindly please help me. I am struggling

here is the jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
$('.error_msge').hide();
 $("#basicForm").validate({
     onkeyup: false,
        showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
        var errors = this.numberOfInvalids();
        
        if (errors) {
            var message = errors == 1 ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted' : 'You have missed ' + errors + ' fields. Please fill before submitted.';
            $("#error_message").html(message);
            $(".error_msge").show();
        } else {
            $(".error_msge").hide();
        }
        this.defaultShowErrors();
    },
    errorPlacement: function () {
        return false;
    },
    highlight: function (element) {
        
        if ($(element).is(':radio'))  {
           
        } else {
            $(element).addClass('errRed');
        }
        $(element).prevAll('label').find('span.required-star').addClass('text-error-red').removeClass('text-error-black');            
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        
        if ($(element).is(':radio')) {
        } else {
            $(element).removeClass('errRed');
        }
        $(element).prevAll('label').find('span.required-star').addClass('text-error-black').removeClass('text-error-red');
        
    },
    
    rules: {
        txt_Jbt: "required",
        txt_Empl: "required",
        txt_Fdob: "required",
        txt_Tdob: "required"
    }
});
```

Here is the fidde [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/evzs82Lw/1/)

Kindly please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your code working in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evzs82Lw/3/). Cloned elements had same value for name  property `<input name="**">`. Validator was considering it as one field although they were different.In addition to this, I assigned rules based on class name. Let me know if this is your expected behaviour.

```
....
$clone.find('[id]').each(function () {
  this.id += '_' + $('.cloned-row3').length + 1 
  this.name += '_' + $('.cloned-row3').length + 1 
});
....
```

EDIT 1:

[Working solution - jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evzs82Lw/9/)

Comment: thanks for the reply one small request once the user click addmore button only one next button should visible is that possible to do that

Comment: hi @Dave i think 2 nd point is missing if the user click add more buton then if the user click next button it should prompt only for the first four fields not for the cloned one kindly please help me

Comment: Confused with both comments.. I didn't undesrstand correctly. Lets say user click's on  Add more 5 times. In that case, there will be 5 NEXT button in page or only one NEXT button.

Comment: only one next button for 5 times and 
my second  comment is if the user click next button without filling any of the data from the cloned one it should say only You have missed 4 fields. Please fill before submitted because he doesn't fill any of the field kindly please help me thanks

Comment: I have joined in the chat

Comment: Updated answer with latest fiddle link

Comment: i have one query is that possible if i have multiple div block can i use your code

Comment: For example say if have cloned-row1, cloned-row2,cloned-row3 with your code is that possible

Comment: If you are asking about nested div's then this script will not work as it is. It might need some minor modification according to the html specified.

Comment: Hi Dave is that possible can you come for a chat

Comment: is that possible can you join in the chat